# DateTimeStamp in Excel (POI)

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I need some help in Apache poi

I am generating excel using Apache POI

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(2);

HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);

cell.setCellValue(someService.getDate());
```

I am getting this Date in DateFormat with TimeStamp **MM/dd/yyyy 00:00:00 AM**

but after generating Excel, it's not showing its proper value in DateFormat.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution is  to set date value as formatted string, I think.

```
...
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
cell.setCellValue(simpleDateFormat.format(someService.getDate()));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Excel what format to apply to the cell, so it knows how to format it

You probably want something like

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();

// Cell styles can be re-used, create only once
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(
    createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));


....
// In your loop
Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
Cell cell = row.createCell(1);

Date value = service.getDate();
cell.setCellValue(value);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```